# Python request module - datetime.date is not serialiable

Tags: python, datetime, python-requests

Im trying to use Python requests module to call a service which returns a Python dict that contains a datetime object...

I get this following errror,

```
  File &quot;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py&quot;, line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File &quot;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py&quot;, line 1733, in wrapper
    json_response = dumps(rv)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py&quot;, line 286, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py&quot;, line 226, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py&quot;, line 296, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py&quot;, line 202, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + &quot; is not JSON serializable&quot;)
TypeError: datetime.date(2014, 4, 16) is not JSON serializable
```

Call stmt:

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8089/allfeeds',verify=False)
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Comment: I believe the service that is returning this response has to use `datetime.strftime` to convert it to string. Not sure if you on the receiving end can prevent this error.

Comment: gtw, use of `verify=False` is not needed as it affects only https (and controls weather it shall verify validity of used certificates or not).

Answer (score 2):

Is your web app written using `bottle`? How do I know that?

Try to make the same call from command line, e.g.:

  `$ curl http://localhost:8089/allfeeds`

I think, that the output of such request will be exactly the same.

the line `print r.text` is just printing the response - not breaking.

In short: the `requests` call works perfectly well, but your web service is returning a string, which looks like a problem. But the problem is in your web app, not on client side.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is from the server. The stdlib-only code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

r = urlopen('http://localhost:8089/allfeeds')
print r.code 
print r.read().decode(r.info().getparam('charset') or 'utf-8')
```

would produce the same result. `r.code` should be 5xx, meaning "Server Error".

`datetime.date` is not JSON serializable; you should modify your server to convert dates into strings e.g., `some_date.isoformat()` or numbers (POSIX timestamp) e.g., `calendar.timegm(some_date.timetuple())` assuming `some_date` is in UTC, see [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).